# Calculating running revenue for cohorts SQL using window function sum over ()

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions, cumsum

I am trying to calculate the running sum (revenue) within each cohort group.
I am using the following query to achieve this:

```
round(sum(SUM(i.subtotal)) OVER (PARTITION BY cft.cohort_start order by invoice_date), 2) AS accrual_cum
```

- cohort_start is the name of the cohort group
- subtotal is the revenue amount

It doesn't help me achieve what I want as it just returns the total sum for each cohort group, whereas what I want is to show me the running sum within each cohort group, so for the first transaction in the first cohort revenue = A , with  the second transaction it becomes  A + B, in the third A + B + C etc.

What am I doing wrong here?

[image: My result]

This is the whole query just in case :

```
WITH 
invoices AS (
    SELECT * FROM {{ source ('bq_raw_data', 'invoices') }}
), 

customer_first_transaction AS (
    SELECT
        customer_id,
        MIN(invoice_date) AS cohort_start
    FROM invoices
    GROUP BY customer_id
)

SELECT
    cft.cohort_start AS customer_cohort,
    invoice_date,
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM (current_date-cft.cohort_start)) AS days_since_cohort_start,
    i.product_id AS product,
    coalesce(companies.region, '0') as region,
    round(SUM(i.subtotal), 2) as accrual_revenue,
    round(sum(SUM(i.subtotal)) OVER (PARTITION BY cft.cohort_start order by invoice_date), 2) AS accrual_cum, 
    case when i.product_id = 'stp_9' then ROUND(SUM(i.subtotal) / 12, 2) 
    else round(SUM(i.subtotal), 2) 
    end AS p_and_l_revenue, 
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN i.product_id = 'stp_9' THEN sum(i.subtotal) / 12 ELSE sum(i.subtotal) END) OVER 
    (PARTITION BY cft.cohort_start ORDER BY invoice_date), 2) 
    AS p_and_l_cum

FROM invoices i
left JOIN customer_first_transaction cft ON i.customer_id = cft.customer_id
LEFT JOIN {{ source('bq_raw_data', 'customers') }} AS customers ON customers.id = i.customer_id
LEFT JOIN {{ source('bq_raw_data', 'companies') }} AS companies ON companies.id = customers.seedlegals_company_id
group by cft.cohort_start, invoice_date, i.product_id, companies.region
order by customer_cohort, invoice_date
```

EDIT:
The result that I get when I am using the query suggested by 0xKevin:

```
    ROUND(i.subtotal, 2) as accrual_revenue,
    ROUND(SUM(i.subtotal) OVER (PARTITION BY cft.cohort_start ORDER BY invoice_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), 2) AS accrual_cum,
    case when i.product_id = 'stp_9' then ROUND(i.subtotal / 12, 2) 
    else ROUND(i.subtotal, 2) 
    end AS p_and_l_revenue,
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN i.product_id = 'stp_9' THEN i.subtotal / 12 ELSE i.subtotal END) OVER (PARTITION BY cft.cohort_start ORDER BY invoice_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), 2) AS p_and_l_cum
```

[Result after the edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1yC6.png)

Comment: make a cte  and then sum it up.

Comment: `order by invoice_date` is non-deterministic, how do you know which order to put the rows in?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query you've written seems almost correct, but there's a slight issue with how you've used the `SUM()` function. The query within the `OVER` clause should not contain a nested `SUM`. The `SUM` inside the window function already calculates the cumulative total; there should not be an additional `SUM` around it.

The correct usage of the window function for calculating a running total, or cumulative sum, would look like this:

```
SUM(i.subtotal) OVER (PARTITION BY cft.cohort_start ORDER BY invoice_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS accrual_cum
```

And for the `p_and_l_cum`, it should be:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN i.product_id = 'stp_9' THEN i.subtotal / 12 ELSE i.subtotal END) OVER (PARTITION BY cft.cohort_start ORDER BY invoice_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS p_and_l_cum
```

Here's how you should modify your query:

```
WITH 
invoices AS (
    SELECT * FROM {{ source ('bq_raw_data', 'invoices') }}
), 
customer_first_transaction AS (
    SELECT
        customer_id,
        MIN(invoice_date) AS cohort_start
    FROM invoices
    GROUP BY customer_id
)
SELECT
    cft.cohort_start AS customer_cohort,
    invoice_date,
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM (current_date - cft.cohort_start)) AS days_since_cohort_start,
    i.product_id AS product,
    coalesce(companies.region, '0') as region,
    ROUND(SUM(i.subtotal), 2) as accrual_revenue,
    ROUND(SUM(i.subtotal) OVER (PARTITION BY cft.cohort_start ORDER BY invoice_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), 2) AS accrual_cum,
    case when i.product_id = 'stp_9' then ROUND(i.subtotal / 12, 2) 
    else ROUND(i.subtotal, 2) 
    end AS p_and_l_revenue,
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN i.product_id = 'stp_9' THEN i.subtotal / 12 ELSE i.subtotal END) OVER (PARTITION BY cft.cohort_start ORDER BY invoice_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), 2) AS p_and_l_cum
FROM invoices i
LEFT JOIN customer_first_transaction cft ON i.customer_id = cft.customer_id
LEFT JOIN {{ source('bq_raw_data', 'customers') }} AS customers ON customers.id = i.customer_id
LEFT JOIN {{ source('bq_raw_data', 'companies') }} AS companies ON companies.id = customers.seedlegals_company_id
GROUP BY cft.cohort_start, invoice_date, i.product_id, companies.region
ORDER BY customer_cohort, invoice_date;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, this it is still not working. I've attached the result that I get in my question  (so the accrual_revenue and accrual_cum columns still don't make sense). 

I've also remove the group by statement as I think it is unnecessary.

Comment: Can you please share some partial data of the invoices table and the desired result by the query? I'd like to test on my end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the link to the file is this: https://github.com/Anya9889/cohort_analytics

I've attached a file with the task description if this is easier for you, but in short the desired output should be a table with the following columns:
-customer cohort
-days since cohort start
-product
-region
-revenue on day (accrual basis)
-revenue on day (profit & loss)
basis)
-cumulative revenue to date (accrual basis),
-cumulative revenue to date (profit & loss basis)

Comment: I've managed to get such a table, but I have a problem with cumulative values as they are not equal to the sum of the individual revenue values.

Comment: Hi @AnyaPasko, I've tried to looked into the github repo that you shared, and done some tests on my end as well. However, seems like there are still some missing tables that you haven't shared and the overall requirements don't make sense to me (or complex to understand for me) in some points. Instead, it'd be better for you to mention the key points only. for example, I assume you would be able to manage everything else if you just get some partial result that you're trying to get.

Comment: So, my question would be; what exactly are you looking to get from the invoices table? Kindly provide the desired result (with some dummy data with in table) that you're looking to get from the invoices table.